# Meaning of "I know it's over 'cause my feet have hit the cold floor"

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

We listened to the song ["Made to love"](https://genius.com/Tobymac-made-to-love-lyrics) by Toby Mac in my classroom. Unfortunately, we could not understand the phrase:

> I know it's over 'cause my feet have hit the cold floor
>   Check my reflection, I ain't feelin' what I see
>   It's no mystery

So, we could not understand why does he talk about his feet and cold floor. We thought that it was an idiom, but we did not find something similar to it. I will be very grateful for explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Poetry (including popular music) is not to be intended to be comprehended literally. When Du Bellay says that nothing Roman is to be perceived in Rome, it cannot be taken literally.

I do not know the song. But when you are in bed with your lover, your feet are normally warm (or soon will be). When the love affair is over, you are metaphorically asked to leave that warm bed of love, then and your feet will be placed on a cold floor. That is when you realize that something warm and comfortable is gone forever.

Comment: I am very grateful for your answer! I could not even think that I need to reason like that. However, this is a very logical explanation.